# Open a Safari window after a form submit in a Progressive Web App

Tags: javascript, html, forms, progressive-web-apps

I used iOs feature 'Add to Home Screen' on my website to access it from the Home Screen.

The problem is that in my app, I have a payment form that is submitted to the bank to initiate the payment. If the customer returns to his home screen (i.e to retrieve the SMS code sent by the 3DSecure), and go back to the app to type it, the "APP" will be reloaded, and he will no longer be able to type his 3DSecure code.

I would like this payment form to be submitted and to open a Safari Window in my Progressive web app, like **target="_blank"** on an *a* tag does.

This way the customer will be able to access the bank payment form (with credit card credentials...) and to proceed the payment, because a Safari window will be opened, and going back to Home or SMS app or anything else would not reload the page. (except if he 'kills' safari app)

I tried a few things:

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://bankurl/...">
    // bank inputs
</form>
```

but this does not open a new safari window, it's still in my PWA.

```
$("#form_bank").find('.btn_send').off('click').click(function () {
    window.open($("#form_bank").attr('action'), '_blank');
});
```

it does the same thing as above.

Note that I choosed to submit the form onclick on a **btn_send** button (but I can submit it differently).

Is there a method to open a Safari or a browser window on a form submition, like it does when you click on a link in a Progressive Web App?

Comment: why you dont user modal for this?

Comment: @SalmanSaleem how would I do that? I want to open a safari window for the persistence

Comment: window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank') this line is working fine, in your case check $("#form_bank").attr('action') value in console if its working fine

Comment: The action attribute is working fine, it's the URL I have to send to the bank to insert payment credentials. If I test directly on Safari, it opens me a new tab. But when I am on my home-screen-added app, it does not.

Comment: do you have any other JavaScript error before executing that line

Comment: No I don't. I finally decided to remove the full-screen meta tag, this way the app is opened with Safari, and everything works fine. The only problem is the address bar, but it's not that annoying when you get used to.